# Preventing duplicate ui-view in AngularJS

Tags: angular-ui-router

## The situation

I have a ui-view component in my template:

```
<div id="innerController" ui-view="stateview"></div>
```

And I have states A and B defined for this view.

## The problem

When I go from state A->B, the rendered DOM looks like this:
[image]

And I got 2 different states on the screen.

## The question

Why do I get 2 different ui-views?

How can I force a single ui-view?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using angular.bootstrap ?